# trigger mouseover on element created by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create links when I press a button and listen for mouseover events of these links.

I use this function to create links:

```
function newlink(){  
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var linkText = document.createTextNode("Test");   
  a.appendChild(linkText);
  a.href ="Page.html";   
  a.setAttribute("class","trigger");
  document.getElementById('divID').appendChild(a);
};
```

In the body I have this button:

```
<input type="button" value="Show Link" onClick="newlink()">
```

In the head I have this function to intercept mouseover:

```
$(function(){
  $('a.trigger').hover(  
    function(e) {       
       alert ('Mouse over intercepted');
       ...  
  });
});
```

When I click the button, the link is created correctly but does not generate the mouseover event. What's the problem?

Comment: Are the links ready and created before the .hover() event is bound?  If you created the links after the event was bound I don't think they'll work without another call to $('a.trigger').hover()

Answer (score 0):

For attaching events to dynamically created HTML elements, use [JQuery's `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), like this:

```
$(document).on('mouseover','a.trigger',function(){
    alert('Mouse over intercepted');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you when you create the link I would add the logic, rather than later via JQuery.

your code would become like this:

```
function newlink(){  
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var linkText = document.createTextNode("Test");   
  a.appendChild(linkText);
  a.href ="Page.html";   
  a.setAttribute("class","trigger"); // <-- you probably don't need this anymore
  a.onmouseover = function() {
     // ... here is your logic !!!
  }
  document.getElementById('divID').appendChild(a);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is a shortcut for [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events, so you can use event delegation using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to register event handlers for mouseenter and mouseleave events for dynamically added contents.

```
function newlink(){  
    $('<a href="Page.html" class="trigger">Test</a>').appendTo('#divID');
};

$(function(){
    $('#divID').on('mouseenter', 'a.trigger', function(){
        console.log('entered')
    })
})
```